# Regex Notepad ++ copy japanese text after and before a character and merge if possible?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to copy text after 日日 and before the かか Line?

- 日日 text text text
- text
- かか

to

- text text text text

Merge the copied text with 2 lines if possible.

Here's an example:

```
日日 すみません。 これはいくらですか？
かか あさきゆめみし　ゑひもせす
日日 禁イす果員か極通ナハ表飯ぜぐ級同ドご著分ぎ熟行ホテヱム敗球うね民西ルレクア難
書中シユ科変せまびぞ帰毎美陸個図と。
かか どうもありがとうございます。
日日 日本語の場合はランダムに生成された文章以外に、著作権が切れた小説などが利用
されることもある。
かか いろはにほへと　ちりぬるを
日日 投ふゃさ闘予き被昭カラ暮最ワウメ線高覧筑エ贈東かをー著嶺天シヲロ停速うてひ刑転
に撮欺内のでル卓討しレッ処周おそ回毎ょきや今格ハワヒナ掲由別えす。
かか わかよたれそ　つねならむ
日日 まっすぐ行ってください。そして、 左／右にまがってください。
かか うゐのおくやま　けふこえて
```

to:

```
すみません。 これはいくらですか？
禁イす果員か極通ナハ表飯ぜぐ級同ドご著分ぎ熟行ホテヱム敗球うね民西ルレクア難書中シユ科変せまびぞ帰毎美陸個図と。
日本語の場合はランダムに生成された文章以外に、著作権が切れた小説などが利用されることもある。
投ふゃさ闘予き被昭カラ暮最ワウメ線高覧筑エ贈東かをー著嶺天シヲロ停速うてひ刑転に撮欺内のでル卓討しレッ処周おそ回毎ょきや今格ハワヒナ掲由別えす。
まっすぐ行ってください。そして、 左／右にまがってください。
```

I've googled it but can't make it work using all regex I found. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your example seems to show all characters on the line after the closing characters need to be deleted as well?

Comment: Also, you seem to be deleting the space after the opening marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need multiple search / replaces:

First, get rid of newlines and trailing characters after end marker:

Search:

```
(日日([^か]|か[^か]|か?\r\n)+)\r\n(.*?かか).*
```

Replace All:

```
\1\3
```

Run this Replace All until no more hits.

Then, get rid of the markers (and the space after the opening one):

Search:

```
日日 (.+?)かか
```

Replace All:

```
\1
```